# Uploading files to busybox machine

Tags: linux, bash, embedded-linux, busybox

For a project of mine I am using a very limited Linux busybox machine.

I am trying to upload files to that machine (connected to me via Ethernet) using telnet.

So far I had several ideas for implementing it:

1. Writing the files in chunks (using `echo -e` on chunks of 128 bytes) to the disk. The idea failed because the echo command doesn't have a `-e` option.
2. Redirecting socket into a file using something like `/dev/tcp/192.168.1.2/12345 > /tmp/file`. The idea failed because the `/dev/` folder didn't contain the `tcp` device.
3. Using utilities such as `nc / ncat / nfqueue` to do so, the idea also failed because none of them exists and I can't install anything on that machine (no `apt-get` / `yum` etc..)
4. Using echo (without the `-e` option) to write a base-64 encoded file to the disk and then decode it. The idea failed because I couldn't find any utility to decode base64 strings

Do you have any creative idea to upload files?

Comment: in your pc machine, download source code of `vsftpd`, cross compile it, and dump it to the system.

Comment: No compiler available on the machine. No downloading option. If a compiler would have been existed I would have compiled `nc`

Comment: or try to mount a `nfs` in your embedded system. i try this once before, it should work too.

Comment: no cross compiler? how does your linux get compiled? there must be one, in some pc box.

Comment: not in your embedded system. cross compiler is in your development machine, ie your desktop or laptop. to make you embedded system have linux installed, at least kernel and busybox have to be compiled. where did you get this system?

Comment: He said cross compiler as in compile for your busybox machine on your Linux box.

Comment: I have a cross compiler for that machine, but I cant transfer files to it (I don't want to install it again)

Comment: Do you by chance have `ftpget` on your busybox machine? I've seen it thrown in so many busybox's. For instance, I have it on my router and it's how I upload custom binaries (like a new busybox!) to it.

Comment: it's very easy to write yourself a piece of c program transferring data in socket if you don't mind. or try `nfs`, it should work.

Comment: Yes, it is easy. but I cant transfer it after it had been compiled (because it is a binary file and I can transfer only text). And I cant transfer it's source code also because the machine doesn't have a compiler installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the fast replies.
I found on the machine a tftp client.

Therefore I could execute:
`/usr/bin/tftp -l /tmp/tst -r testfile.txt -g <server ip>`

after opening a tftp server on .

Answer (score 0):

See if your busybox build includes [rx](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#rx) .

This will give you XMODEM receive functionality on your target.

I asked our software group to add it to our image; it was added with very little effort.

Comment: It's a great idea. However I didn't had it.